# Why is $\|AA^T(Ax-b)\| \leq \|A^TA\|\cdot\|(Ax-b)\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please explain what results we use to get the following:

$$\|AA^T(Ax-b)\| \leq \|A^TA\|\cdot\|(Ax-b)\|,$$

where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix; $b$ and $x$ are $m \times 1$ vectors, and $\|.\|$ is the $2$-norm.

Comment: This can't be true. Let $A=1, b=0, x=2$. Then the above inequality gives $2^2 \leq 2$, which is clearly false. I would suspect that the square on the lhs should be removed, then the result follows from the fact that $\|M\| = \|M^T\|$ (assuming the Euclidean norm, and a real matrix).

Comment: This is clearly wrong because it does not have the right scaling behaviour.  It should be $\|A A^T (Ax - b)\| \le \|A^T A\| \|Ax - b\|$.  $\|A^T A\|$ and $\|A A^T\|$ are equal because we're using the spectral norm and $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: thanks @RobertIsrael! Could you please explain to me why the square isn't valid?
Wait.. does that mean that we're not using Cauchy Schwarz at all?

Comment: Is the inequality in your comment a trivial result? or does it derive from something? We were only introduced to matrix norms this week.. so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think $||M|| = ||M^T||$ gives the desired result, because the order of A and $A^T$ stay the same after a transpose: i.e. $(AA^T)^T = AA^T$

Comment: @RobertIsrael how can AB and BA have the same non-zero eigenvalues if AB and BA are of different dimensions? In this example, $AA^T$ is m x m whereas $A^TA$ is n x n?

Comment: @James: Because of the "nonzero". The larger of $AB$ and $BA$ has additional eigenvalues that are all $0$.

Comment: @James: You are right, I should have written $\|AB\| = \|BA\|$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, and $AB x = \lambda x$, then multiplying by $B$ gives $BA (Bx) = \lambda (Bx)$ ($\neq 0$), hence they share the same non zero eigenvalues.

Comment: And $\|AB\|^2 = \lambda_{\max}((AB)^T AB) = \lambda_{\max}(AB (AB)^T) = \|BA\|^2$.

Comment: @James: The result follows from the fact that for an induced norm, $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\| \|x\|$.

Answer (score 1):

For any matrix $A$ and vector $b$, using Cauchy-Schwarz in the second inequality,
$$
\|Ab\|_2^2=\sum_j\left|\sum_kA_{jk}b_k\right|^2\leq\sum_j\left(\sum_k|A_{jk}b_k|\right)^2
\leq\sum_j\left(\left(\sum_k|A_{jk}|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_k|b_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\right)^2
=\sum_j\sum_k|A_{jk}|^2\sum_k|b_k|^2=\|A\|_2^2\|b\|_2^2.
$$
So $\|Ab\|_2\leq\|A\|_2\|b\|_2$. Now you can use $AA^T$ instead of $A$ and $Ax-b$ instead of $b$.